# Verification of Basic Proof in Spivak Calculus (Induction)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

I have began working through Spivak's Calculus book and trying to do the problems at the end of the chapters. I am rather new to proof, so forgive the naivety of this type of question.

I am wanting to make sure that my method/ understanding of some of the proofs are correct, as I do not have solutions.

One I am wondering about for example is ,

$\mathbf{Q:}$  Prove that every natural number is even or odd.

$\mathbf{My \space answer:}$

First of all, let "A" be the set containing all natural numbers that are either even or odd. It is clear that $1 \in A$ because 1 is odd.

Now, by induction, suppose that "n" is in $A$.

Then n is either even , or n is odd

if $n$ is even, then it can be written as $2m$ where $m$ is an integer, and hence $n+1=2m+1$ hence $n+1$ is odd, and is in $A$.

If n is odd, then it can be written as $2m+1$ where $m$ is an integer, and hence $n+1=2m+2=2(m+1)$ and hence $n+1$ is even, so it is in $A$.

Is this sufficient to conclude then via induction that infact A is the set of all natural numbers?

Is there anything I am missing or should be careful about? Thanks everyone

Comment: Seems good to me!

Comment: Depending on your definition of odd the base case is OK. I would then take as $P_k$ the proposition that for $k\in \mathbb{N}, k$ is either odd or even. Then the base case is $P_1$ which is true as you observe.  Now assume $P_k$, then show that $k+1$ is either odd or even, hence $P_{k+1}$. Then by induction you will have shown that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}, P_n$ and so for any $n \in \mathbb{N}, n$ is odd or even.

Comment: @Quality How far are you planning to go with Spivak? Are you a student in Canada? I started self-studying Spivak too and I am a student in Canada too

Comment: @Real Yes I am as well. And I am not to sure yet, I have previously taken calculus with Stewarts book. I am trying to go over Spivak as much as I can as it seems much more rigorous and I want to make sure my foundations are solid for real analysis. I am also using a bit of Herstein's Algebra as well, so I don't know how far I will get into Spivak. How about yourself?

Comment: @Quality Oh that is nice to hear yeah I am currently in SFU, using Stewart's book as well for calc 2 but doing a little bit of Spivak on the side as I am preparing for an analysis course next semester.